# postfix how to see what the $default* values are

Tags: linux, email, postfix, mail-server

In my post fix configuration files I keep finding options / settings like these

> var = $default_values
>   option = $default_values

For example this is out put form a grep I ran.

> /conf/main.cf.default:initial_destination_concurrency = 5
>   ./conf/main.cf.default:lmtp_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit
>   ./conf/main.cf.default:lmtp_destination_concurrency_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_limit

I would like to know what those $defautl values are. How can I find out. Are they kept in a files that I can read some where. Is there a man page I can go to.

The postfix documentation is extensive, I have been read all morning. I still have not found how to find out what the defaults on my installation are. I don't know if the distro I am using Ubuntu 8.04 made changes to the default values before shipping. The only way for to check is see where / how those default values are actually set.

I know what I need to do to fix a problem I have I just don't want to make changes with out understanding how it can affect other part of the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`postconf -d` will show default values of every variable.

The `default_` prefix, however, is just a part of the variable name, and it can be changed like any other variable. You will want to use just **`postconf` (without any options)** to see the *current* value of that `$default_....` variable.

(On a related note, `postconf -n` displays only variables that have been *changed*.)